# How to get the nuget cache folder location

Tags: .net-core

I am writing a dotnet core tool and need to find a sibling nuget package from my tool. If i was on full .net framework i could have found it with

```
Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile),".nuget...");
```

Anyone have a sugestion to find the package folder when not having the Environment stuff avaible? (If nothing exists, i can live with it not working on unix)

the dotnet core tools can be used in project.json tools section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Nuget 3-3.5 you may use the following to get cache folder location

```
nuget locals packages-cache -list
```

After Nuget 3.5 this is currently not supported, but accordingly to [this](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/3591) opened issue, Nuget team will consider those feature in future.

Comment: On the 18th Oct 2017, the issue was closed with `WontFix`