# How to get the nuget cache folder location programmatically

Tags: .net, nuget, nuget-package

I need to get from a .NET app (that is not .NET Core app) the list of directories where NuGet stores its packages.

I know by default it is in `C:\Users\[YourUsername]\.nuget\packages` so an option is to iterate over all users assuming the current Windows user that runs the process owns the right to access other users data. Moreover if this default dir is changed by the user I am stuck.

An answer is provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41533938/27194) through

```
nuget locals packages-cache -list
```

but it is not .NET code and it seems to be an obsolete option according to the answer.

---

Moreover I'd like to understand the logic of .NET Core NuGet packages locations, because I can see some .NET Core packages in 3 locations:

- `C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App`  (don't contain AspNetCore packages)
- `C:\Users\[UserName]\.nuget\packages`  (do contain AspNetCore packages)
- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages`  (do contain AspNetCore packages)

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/how-to-detect-installed-versions?pivots=os-windows#check-runtime-versions 
dotnet --list-runtimes
For the items in this folder
C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In order to achieve this you need to use the same code and libraries as `nuget.exe` does:

1. Install nuget package `NuGet.Configuration` to your project
2. Add `using NuGet.Configuration` at the top of your file
3. Use the following code(which `nuget.exe` uses itself under the hood):

```cs
var settings = Settings.LoadDefaultSettings(null);
Console.WriteLine(SettingsUtility.GetGlobalPackagesFolder(settings));
```

You also can check nuget.exe with `ILSpy` to figure out how it works or use relevant source code at github [NuGet/NuGet.Client](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client)

Comment: We won't have the time to test this right now but it sounds good and will post about my experience trying this. Meantime I check this question as answered thanks